# Query available storage on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to determine how much free storage is left on the iphone using the iphone sdk?
I'd like to adapt the cache size depending on how much space is actually left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here is an example: [Mac/iPhone: Show Available Usable Disk Space](http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/27/maciphone-show-availble-useable-diskspace/). They provide a class you can plug in as well, but a lot of it is simply formatting the result.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
struct statfs tStats;
statfs([[paths lastObject] cString], &tStats);
availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
```

Comment: Be careful of the code in 'Mac/iPhone: Show Available Usable Disk Space'. The code ignores a return value from statfs, which appears to be leading to crashes for some folks. Its too bad that a company which claims to specialize in the platform puts junk out for copy/paste headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Error checking...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
struct statfs tStats;
float availableDisk = 0;
if (statfs([[paths lastObject] cString], &tStats) != -1)
    availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
```